# Cesium Billboard Canvas Turns Black

Tags: javascript, canvas, cesiumjs

So I am dynamically creating and updating popups in my Cesium application and it works great. However, after some time of the application running, the billboards turn black and remain black until I refresh the page. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this bug?

The following code is the basis of what I am doing, loadPopup() is responsible for generating the billboard with a canvas as its image element. updatePopup() is called synchronously as the application is running to update the position of the billboard element.

```js
//creates the popup first
function loadPopup(id, type, name, data) {
  viewer.entities.add({
    id : id,
    name : name,
    position : data.position,
    billboard :  {
      image : createPopupCanvas(id, type, name, data),
      verticalOrigin : Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM,
      scaleByDistance : new Cesium.NearFarScalar(1500, 2, 80000000, 0.25)
    }
  });  
}

//updates popup synchronously
function updatePopup(id, type, name, data) {
  var newPosition = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(data.lon, data.lat, 99999);
  var currPopup = viewer.entities.getById(id);
  
  if (currPopup != undefined) {
    currPopup.position = newPosition;
  }
}

//creates a canvas element to display some stuff from the data table
function createPopupCanvas(id, type, name, data) {
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
   context.fillText(data.stuff1, id, 105, 60);
   context.fillText(data.stuff2, id, 105, 70);
  
  return canvas;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this Rafael, I'm seeing similar behaviour, but only on mobile devices.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce. Can you please share a working example in which I can see the effect?